# Redirecting STDOUT/STDERR in perl to a txt file?

Tags: perl, shell, environment

I'm trying to log the output of the command:

`innobackupex --incremental $INC1_BACKUP_FOLDER --incremental-basedir=$BASEDIR_FULL $SLAVE_INFO > $PATH_TO_LOG/log_inc1.txt 2>&1`;

however it does not write to file rather prints on STDOUT.

This works and logs to file:

`innobackupex $DB_USER_INFO $FULL_BACKUP_FOLDER $SLAVE_INFO > $PATH_TO_LOG/log_full.txt 2>&1`;

however this does not log to file:

`innobackupex --incremental $INC1_BACKUP_FOLDER --incremental-basedir=$BASEDIR_FULL $SLAVE_INFO > $PATH_TO_LOG/log_inc1.txt 2>&1`;

the other solution I tried is:

```
open (INC1_RESULT,">$PATH_TO_LOG/log_inc1.txt");
my $incr1_backup_result = `innobackupex --incremental $INC1_BACKUP_FOLDER --incremental-basedir=$BASEDIR_FULL $SLAVE_INFO`;
print INC1_RESULT $incr1_backup_result;
close INC1_RESULT;
```

which did not work either because it will only write to the file after the command completes execution. I need to tail the log when the command is running.

Comment: Are you sure it's not writing on STDERR instead?

Comment: Added shell & environment tags

Comment: Added 2>&1 missing command.
@Cfreak i'm not really sure. How do I find that out ? Sorry if it is a really basic question but kinda new to this.

Comment: the problem i m facing is that this works perfectly

`innobackupex $DB_USER_INFO $FULL_BACKUP_FOLDER $SLAVE_INFO > $PATH_TO_LOG/log_full.txt 2>&1`;

however this does not,

innobackupex --incremental $INC1_BACKUP_FOLDER --incremental-basedir=$BASEDIR_FULL $SLAVE_INFO > $PATH_TO_LOG/log_inc1.txt 2>&1;

Googling for this did not help.

Comment: You need to redirect both to the file. See @psema4's answer

Comment: Tried this too http://stackoverflow.com/a/758622/1397501, it still does not write to file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming bash in a *nix environment, try redirecting both stdout and stderr to the text file (note the ampersand):

```
innobackupex --incremental $INC1_BACKUP_FOLDER --incremental-basedir=$BASEDIR_FULL $SLAVE_INFO &> $PATH_TO_LOG/log_inc1.txt
```

More info in the [Introduction to BASH Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).  If you're in a different environment, check it's documentation on stream redirection.

--

According to [the documentation](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/innobackupex/how_innobackupex_works.html?id=percona-xtrabackup%3ainnobackupex%3ahow_it_works):

> Note that the STDERR of innobackupex is not written in any file. You will have to redirect it to a file, e.g., innobackupex OPTIONS 2> backupout.log.

Which redirects stderr to a file.  OP notes (in comment below) that redirecting both stderr and stdout is not working as expected.

Comment: I tried your solution it still prints it to the output instead of printing to the file.

Comment: I've been down this road before, it can get pretty frustrating I know.  What's your environment look like? Are you using Bash on Linux?

Comment: Just added a line I noticed in the documentation - can you try using 2> log_inc1.txt and see if it writes the file?

Comment: Tried using 2> log_inc1.txt but still nothing in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

There, it should now do both i.e. print out to STDOUT and write to Log-

```
innobackupex --incremental $INC1_BACKUP_FOLDER --incremental-basedir=$BASEDIR_FULL $SLAVE_INFO | tee -a $PATH_TO_LOG/log_inc1.txt
```

Or just write to log

```
innobackupex --incremental $INC1_BACKUP_FOLDER --incremental-basedir=$BASEDIR_FULL $SLAVE_INFO >> $PATH_TO_LOG/log_inc1.txt
```

Comment: I tried both solutions but it did not write to the log file in both cases.